# difference between accuracy from confusion matrix and validation accuracy

Tags: deep-learning

What is the difference between accuracy obtained from confusion matrix and validation accuracy obtained after several epochs?

I am new to deep learning

Answer (score 0):

The validation accuracy (from each epoch) is the accuracy obtained from each trial (combination of parameters/weight). That is not to be used for reporting. It is just logging of the status of the training/learning process.

If you want to measure accuracy of a trained (fixed/frozen) model (be it deep learning or whatever algorithm learning), use a separate validation set and measure it using confusion matrix yourselve (there is metric package in sklearn).